# How to tell the difference between a jquery object and a dict in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, types

```
>>> var jq = $('body');
>>> var di = {hello: 'world'};

>>> typeof jq == typeof di;
true
```

This is not true :(. a dict object and a jquery object aren't the same type. Is this sort of thing possible with javascript?

Comment: In JavaScript, `typeof jq` and `typeof di` will return "object" because that's really the only object type that exists.  What makes objects different is their members and their prototype.

Comment: This is true, in the sense that both `jq` and `di` are of the same [JavaScript type](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Variables_and_Types) (`object`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typeof both variables is `Object`. I think you are going for [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Instanceof_Operator).

```
jq instanceof jQuery // -> true
di instanceof jQuery // -> false
```

Comment: $('body') instanceof jQuery // true

Answer (score 3):

use jQuery.isPlainObject

```
jQuery.isPlainObject(di) === true
jQuery.isPlainObject(jq) === false
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to tell the difference?  I've found that it's better to think about this problem from the other direction: in the immediate circumstance where you have an object of unknown provenance, what are the different possibilities?  In other words, can it really be *anything*, or is it just that you need to know what method to call?

It's a matter of personal preference, but generally I find it easier to do duck-typing checks more loosely, and just check to see if a couple of "signal" properties are present on the mystery object.